# Update a column based on another's table column value

Tags: sql-server, update

I have a table **Users**

```
+----------+----------+
|  ID_EMP  | isActive |
+----------+----------+
|   100    +    1     +
|   101    +    1     +
+----------+----------+
```

and a table **UsersInfo**

```
+----------+------------+
|  ID_EMP  |   FRDATE   |
+----------+------------+
|   100    +   null     +
|   101    + 2019-10-10 +
+----------+------------+
```

I tried to update column `Users.isActive` with 0 when the `UsersInfo.FRDATE` is not null. I read similar questions and ended up with the following query, which is not working as expected, as it is updating all the columns with `0`

```
UPDATE [dbMyDB].[dbo].[Users]
SET [dbMyDB].[dbo].[Users].[isActive] = 0
FROM [dbMyDB].[dbo].[Users] USERS
INNER JOIN
    [dbMyDB].[dbo].[UsersInfo] INFO
ON USERS.ID_EMP = INFO.ID_EMP
WHERE EXISTS 
(
    SELECT FRDATE FROM [dbMyDB].[dbo].[UsersInfo]
    WHERE FRDATE IS NOT NULL
)
```

what I am missing?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE users 
SET isActive=0 
FROM users 
JOIN userinfo 
    ON users.id_emp = info.id_emp 
   AND frdate IS NOT NULL
```

?

Comment: Thanks it worked! It was simpler that I thought :)